# Cannot select element with combination of :not() and :first-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

While doing regular CSS, I found something wrong.
I have combination of `:not(.class)` selector and `:first-child` selector. Separately these two are working good. The `red` row should be red, but it isn't.

Here is snippet:

```css
table tr td {
  background: lightblue;
}

table tr.test td {
  background: lightgreen;
}

table tr:not(.test):first-child td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr class="test">
        <td>green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="test">
        <td>green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blue</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I think, it should be like so: `tr:not(.test)` selects all `<tr>` elements which has no `test` class, then `:first-child` selects the first of those.

I don't want to use additional classes or change HTML.

Am I doing something wrong, or it's just some bug?

(I'm running Chrome 78.0.3904.87)

Comment: The selector `:first-child` matches the first child of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, you have written

```
 table tr:not(.test):
```

Above line of code means you are fetching all the `tr` with no `.test` class.

```
 table tr:not(.test):first-child td {
 background: red;
}
```

And this code is matching the first child of the table. To understand it try changing the  `first-child` to `last-child`. And you will see the changes.

I will recommend going through the docs of the selector on [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/)